# Showing current user instance in edit profile form

Tags: python, django

So I have this view which displays my `UserProfileForm`. As far as I can tell the logic of what's going on makes sense. It should (1) automatically pull the profile info from the currently logged in user and (2) save it when submitted. The only problem is that it does neither of those two things.

I have looked around SO for how to do this as well as some other tutorials but it still won't do the trick.

The view:

```
def editProfileView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('users:explore')
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'users/userprofile_edit_form.html', args)
```

Not sure how relevant seeing the form itself is but this is what it looks like:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}))
    profile_pic = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}), required=False)
    location = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}))
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}))
    user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    website = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}))
    about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}))
    twitter = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}))
    dribbble = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}))
    github = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}))

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'profile_pic',
            'location',
            'title',
            'user_type',
            'website',
            'about',
            'twitter',
            'dribbble',
            'github'
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the UserProfile model is a separate model from the user model and connected via some foreignkey. I can't see the model in your post but if the foreignkey has related_name='user_profile' you should change

```
instance = request.user
```

to

```
instance = request.user.user_profile
```